# group_by and mutate based on string value

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am attempting to group_by and filter a table, and eventually, mutate a new column based on a specific string value.
The table I have looks like this-

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | age |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | gender |
| 2 | gender |
| 2 |  |
| 3 |  |

And what i'm attempting to do here is to mutate a new column that populates "1" based on the specific value, but for all the same IDs. This was i'm able to filter out all the id's that have a specific value. Say that value is "gender", I would like the new column values and table to be-

| id | value | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | age |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 | gender | 1 |
| 2 | gender | 1 |
| 2 |  | 1 |
| 3 |  |  |

The way I have attempted this in the past is that I'm able to mutate a new column and do a group_by if there is n_distinct == 1, for example

`new_table <- table %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(result = if_else(value=="gender" & n_distinct(value)>1,"1",""))`

But this wont work since id 1 also has `n_distinct(value)>1`.
Also open to completely changing my method for something that works,
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can look for `any` `gender` value in a `id`

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%  group_by(id) %>% mutate(result = if(any(value=="gender")) 1 else '' )
```

If you are ok having 1/0 as a result you can also use -

```
table %>% group_by(id) %>%  mutate(result = as.integer(any(value=="gender")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`%in%` works well here:

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(result = +("gender" %in% value))
# # A tibble: 6 x 3
# # Groups:   id [3]
#      id value    result
#   <int> <chr>     <int>
# 1     1 "age"         0
# 2     1 ""            0
# 3     2 "gender"      1
# 4     2 "gender"      1
# 5     2 ""            1
# 6     3 ""            0
```

### base R

```r
+as.logical(ave(dat$value, dat$id, FUN = function(z) "gender" %in% z))
# [1] 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

The `as.logical` is required because `ave` always returns the same class as its first argument (`dat$value`) regardless of what class the `FUN` returns. We don't technically need the `+` before it (which converts `TRUE` to `1`), but since you said you wanted an integer (I think ... or is it a character `"1"`?), I thought I'd shortcut convert it.

---

Data

```r
dat <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), value = c("age", "", "gender", "gender", "", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is also

```
library(dplyr)
table %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(result = +(!is.na(match('gender', value))))
```